# Chrome fails to free memory, garbage collection doesn't occur as expected (Mootools/MochaUI library)

Tags: google-chrome, garbage-collection, mootools, javascript

**Background**: I'm currently working on an intranet site that makes use of the MochaUI library (working from the [virtual desktop demo](http://mochaui.org/demo/demo-virtual-desktop.html)). I'm using Mootools 1.2.4 and MochaUI 0.9.7. The windows that are opened in my "virtual desktop" implementation load their content via iframes. Some of the loaded pages are pretty hefty in terms of css and scripting, so it's important that Window objects are adequately garbage collected when the user closes a window. This is ostensibly taken care of by the library (it does do a fair job when using Firefox).

**Update**
The originally posted question had become overly long from subsequent edits/updates. The title wasn't accurate anymore, so I changed that as well. Also, see my answer below for a partial solution.

Here are the essential points:

1. **Chrome goofs up like so:**

   - Chrome fails to free up memory allocated for MochaUI window objects when they're closed. Instead, Chrome's memory usage freezes (literally) at the level reached after the window has finished loading its iframe content, setting a lower bound on memory usage until the page is refreshed.
   - Memory used by the process continues to increase with subsequent window openings/closings. Eventually, some type of cap is reached, and the memory usage stops climbing as steeply/starts to oscillate instead of jump up dramatically.
   - This problem is most apparent when the windows in question are loading fairly hefty (memory-wise) iframe content. The window I'm using for all testing purposes loads a 580 kb page (uncached) in its iframe.
2. **Strangely enough, the expected garbage collection *does* take place, when**

   - the browser is subsequently minimized
   - another tab is opened in the same browser window
   - a Memory Timeline is being recorded in Developer Tools. (comedy option)
   - Does this behavior suggest any possible approaches to solving #1?

Comment: Very interesting question and good explanation. I'm not exactly sure what the culprit is, although I will warn you there's a chance that there won't be a solution. Or if there is one, not an easy one. Google takes a very lazy approach to programming. Though Chrome seems to load fastest and use least memory of every major browser, it's riddled with bugs I wouldn't dream of in Firefox or Opera. Same with Android vs. iOS.

Comment: I posted a very detailed/lengthy version of this question on Google's Chrome Webmaster help forum and did not get a reply, so this time I decided to make it more to the point! I agree that this seems like a bug (or a quirk of how Chrome determines which objects to be garbage collected). It's as if there's a more strenuous level of garbage collection that occurs when Chrome is minimized, and my window objects aren't fully garbage by Chrome's standards, perhaps. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @steven_desu: Not only does Google take a lazy approach to programming, it also seems uttlerly apathetic towards any kind of complaints or problems its users come up with.

Comment: To be fair, Chrome handles the MochaUI library's canvas/mootools effects much more gracefully than Firefox. As well, it does the garbage collection quite well, as good or better than Firefox based on my tests, it just doesn't want to do it at the right time. It would be the superior option for this particular "virtual desktop" application, if not for the weird garbage collection behavior that, for whatever reason, involves the Open/Minimized state of the browser.

Comment: It sure sounds a lot like you're trying to debug memory usage with Taskmgr.exe.  Yes, the working set gets trimmed when you minimize a window.  That's a measure that has *nothing* to do with leaks.

Comment: Well, for my explicit tests of this behavior I used the memory usage stats shown on the "stats for nerds" page in Chrome's Task Manager. The behavior of the relevant Chrome process in Taskmgr.exe follows a similar pattern...Should I be looking somewhere else besides those two places?

Comment: you should stop right here and have a look at what's happening with mochaui first since it's been taken over by Chirs Dotty (sp?). Essentially, he has fixed and rewritten largely everything, making it in-line with mootools 1.2.5 and now 1.3. a new mochaui release is in the pipelines by the end of the year. Take a look at the threads on the google users group and check it out from github - perhaps you are fixing something that has already been addressed.

Comment: @Dimitar: Yes, I think this problem, or something related, is on the radar (http://github.com/mui/mochaui/issues#issue/55). Although, this question doesn't just involve memory leaks/library problems, but also some weird Chrome behavior re: canvas elements and the mootools element.destroy() function (see my answer below...).

Comment: I'm facing exactly same symptoms in a reactjs app, which renders iframes. And it looks like the problem is connected to those iframes being on the same domain (deployed to different subdomains, but chrome batches them all into one process based on a high level domain name). Result is: memory for those frames is never released, I see it growing to 10gb, 15gb, if i leave the app running, which is ridiculous

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this was tested in Windows, but if so keep in mind that whenever you minimize a window in windows it moves all data to the pagefile. When opening the window again it won't move the memory blocks back unless the program tries to access them, and thus any garbage stays in the pagefile but isn't actually collected.

If you'd automate it, it would not only slow the program down it would also not help with any memory issues.

see the following url for a bit more info

https://micksmix.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/why-does-task-manager-show-an-applications-memory-usage-drop-after-minimizing-it-to-the-the-taskbar/

Comment: All the machines on the intranet that will be using the site run Windows XP, I believe. I hadn't considered that issue with the pagefile, though automating/tricking Chrome to its Minimized state (somehow, to whatever effect) was a long-shot concept...Ideally, I would find some way to change my javascript code so that Chrome recognizes the objects to be garbage collected as per usual.

Comment: Have you tried setting the variables/objects to null once you are done with them?

Comment: As far as I grasp the library's functions that handle the window-closing behavior, it appears to set all the relevant objects to null when a window closes. The content loaded in the windows (in iframes) is more my own code, and it's somewhat messy and probably contributes to leaks...however, I should note that Firefox clearly frees up memory when windows close (to the tune of 3-5 MB over about 5 seconds). The memory usage of the relevant Chrome process, on the other hand, stays static when windows are closed, and the only thing that makes it decrease is minimizing the browser.

Comment: it does use `windowEl.destroy();` which maps to an element prototype function that empties node, disposes (removes from dom), cleans whats left (extra security) and so forth. which version of mootools is being referenced?

Comment: Windows pages a program out entirely when you minimize it?  Sorry, that's just nonsense.

Comment: @Maynard It seems to be a bit more conservative in windows 7, but it still does it if you don't have a lot of free memory. Added an url to answer which has a bit more in depth info

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
The following changes to the MochaUI closingJobs function are a **big** improvement over what I previously posted here. The main change is now the iframe's onunload event is manually called by changing the src property, instead of being fired when the windowEl.destroy method removes the iframe from the DOM. (got the idea from [here](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/forum/general/general-discussion/using-dojo-iframes-solving-memory-leak)).

If you want to use this code, just delete the existing closingJobs function and copy paste this code in its place. It *should* work with both 0.9.7 and 0.9.8 MochaUI, and either Mootools 1.2.4 or 1.3.

---

```
closingJobs: function(windowEl){        
    windowEl.setStyle('visibility', 'hidden');
    var instances = MUI.Windows.instances;
    var instance_id = windowEl.id   
    var cleanup_delay = 50;

  /*
  Reset canvases with width/height = 0.
  This pretty reliably frees a few hundred Kb of
  memory in chrome.
  */        
    instances[instance_id].canvasControlsEl.width = 0;
    instances[instance_id].canvasControlsEl.height = 0; 
    instances[instance_id].canvasEl.width = 0;
    instances[instance_id].canvasEl.height = 0;         

    if(instances[instance_id].options.loadMethod == 'iframe')
    {
 /*
 The following line determines how long to delay the execution of
 the windowEl.destroy function. The line below gives 10 milliseconds 
 per DOM element in the iframe's document.
 You could probably do just as well with a hard-coded value.
 */         
        cleanup_delay = instances[instance_id].iframeEl.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName("*").length * 10;              

 /*
 Set the Browser property in the iframe's window to Internet Explorer.
 This causes Mootools to run its purge function, which iterates over
 all the iframe document's DOM elements, removing events/attributes etc.
 Assuming you have mootools included in the iframe content.     
 */
        if(instances[instance_id].iframeEl.contentDocument.defaultView.MooTools)
        {           
            if(instances[instance_id].iframeEl.contentDocument.defaultView.MooTools.version.contains("1.3"))                
                instances[instance_id].iframeEl.contentDocument.defaultView.Browser.ie = true;
            else        
                instances[instance_id].iframeEl.contentDocument.defaultView.Browser.Engine.trident = true;
        }                   

        instances[instance_id].iframeEl.src = "javascript:false";
    }       

    MUI.cleanWindow.delay(cleanup_delay, null, windowEl);       
},  

cleanWindow: function(windowEl)
{                               
    var instances = MUI.Windows.instances;
    var instance_id = windowEl.id
    if (Browser.ie){
        windowEl.dispose();
    }
    else {
        windowEl.destroy();
    }       
    instances[instance_id].fireEvent('onCloseComplete');

 /*
 Changed - Only execute getWindowWithHighestZindex() and focusWindow() 
 functions if there will actually be open windows after the 
 current one closes.
 */
    if (instances[instance_id].options.type != 'notification' && instances.__count__ > 1){
        var newFocus = MUI.getWindowWithHighestZindex();
        MUI.focusWindow(newFocus);
    }       
    if (this.loadingWorkspace) this.windowUnload();
    if (MUI.Dock && $(MUI.options.dock) && instances[instance_id].options.type == 'window'){
        var currentButton = $(instances[instance_id].options.id + '_dockTab');
        if (currentButton != null){
            MUI.Dock.dockSortables.removeItems(currentButton).destroy();
            currentButton = null; //Is this necessary?
        }           
        MUI.Desktop.setDesktopSize();
    }

    //Changed - moved this to the end of the function.
    delete instances[instance_id];  
}
```

Comment: also, which version of mootools is being used. mootools 1.3 has somewhat simplified element.prototype.destroy so it looks like this: http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Element/Element.js#L677 vs the old one http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/1.2x/Source/Element/Element.js#L579 that goes to the weird `clean()` function above.

Comment: 1.2.4. I'm seeing the same stuff happen with 1.3 (with the 0.9.7 MochaUI build, that is). In my test I did use the compatibility layer, though I'm unsure if that is a factor here. The fix I suggest above has the same affect on Chrome's memory behavior with 1.3 as with 1.2.4. All that could change, though: based on your first comment I poked around some more in mocha ui's github -- I was totally unaware that the 0.9.8 branch had so much recent activity! Thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: no worries! the old mochaui has been... difficult to work with. i am still supporting my own branch due to the huge number of fixes i have had to implement and now using 0.9.8 or 1.0 will be near impossible! oh well!